# Trying to scrape a hotel booking website. Not able to retrieve the prize

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68662594/16452840).
[Trying to scrape this site](https://www.tunisiebooking.com/)

Expected output is :

Name of the Hotel

First arrangement option : its prize

Code I have tried so far:

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/")
#code to choose the option "Sousse" ,date- 06/08/21, and click on "Rechercher".

hotels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')]")
for hotel in hotels:
    name = hotel.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text
    argmts = hotel.find_element_by_class_name("angle_active").text
    prize = hotel.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'prixtotal_')]").text
    print(name)
    print(argmts + ':' + prize)
driver.quit()
```

The output I get:

```
Petit dejeuner:60
Tui Blue Scheherazade
Demi pension:60
Golf Residence GAS
Petit dejeuner:60
Sindbad Center GAS
Logement seul:60 ...
```

Applied `scrolling` effect and `time.sleep`. But the `prize` remains same, its doesn't get the prize of the respective Hotel. Not sure where its going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has worked for me, with the `.get_attribute`

```
driver.get("https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/")
select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ville_des']")
option = Select(select)

option.select_by_index(3)
#code to choose the option "Sousse" ,date- 06/08/21, and click on "Rechercher".
search = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"((//div[@class='col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5'])[1])")))
search.click()
hotels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')]")
for hotel in hotels:
name = hotel.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text

argmts = hotel.find_element_by_class_name("angle_active").text

#taken the help of contains() and tried to get the static part of the element ID.
prize = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@id,'prixtotal_')]").get_attribute("innerText")
print(name)
print(argmts + ':' + prize)
driver.quit()
```

**O/P**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdYJX.png

Answer (score 2):

I would get each hotel element separately, move to it and then get inner elements details.
Also, the best way to get elements inside element is with XPath staring with dot `.` as below.
Try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)


hotels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')]")
for i in range (1, len(hotels)+1):
    hotel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair')])[" + str(i) + "]")
    actions.move_to_element(hotel).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    name = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//h3").text
    argmts = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='angle_active']").text
    prize = hotel.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[starts-with(@id,'prixtotal_')]").text
    print(name)
    print(argmts + ':' + prize)
driver.quit()
```